# Registering jQuery with ScriptManager

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager

I am using the [Dynamic Drive 'Animated Collapsible DIV v2.4'](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm) script - My page has 8 div's each of which I wish to be able to expand and collapse.

I register the jQuery from `Page_Load` as follows: (I also tried in `Page_PreRender` but same problem)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Me, Me.GetType, "AnimatedCollapse", Page.ResolveUrl("~/include/animatedcollapse.js"))
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Me, Me.GetType, "BensJQuery", Page.ResolveUrl("~/include/BensJquery.js"))
```

The `animatedcollapse.js` file is what was downloaded from the Dynamic Drive website. `BensJquery` is a file with the main `$(document).ready(function () {` handler which initialises the animated collapse script.

Without using an `UpdatePanel` on my page, this is **working perfectly**.

However when I introduce an `UpdatePanel` to the page which contains all the 8 `<div>` elements, the page no longer functions as expected.

When I cause a postback (e.g. click a button), the functionality all breaks. All the `<div>` elements collapse and cannot be expanded again, the page just generally breaks, but there are no JavaScript errors displayed or .NET errors in the events viewer.

What do I need to do so that I can use an UpdatePanel successfully with this jQuery?

**EDIT**
I have solved this problem by not using one all-encompassing `UpdatePanel` but instead using them more sparingly and only when needed, which is probably quite a bit better now anyway.

Thanks,
bgs264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by not using one all-encompassing `UpdatePanel` but instead using them more sparingly and only when needed, which is probably quite a bit better now anyway.